# How to get "Find" command to ONLY return files and no directories

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm developing a little desktop application that lists the files in a given directory.

[image: app]

The table on the left gets compared to the table on the right. If anything on the right is missing, the text of the files on the left will turn red. Simple.

What I'm throwing at these tables is a path that contains multiple subfolders of images.
These are saved as a variable so I cannot explicitly declare "omit a directory with this name".

Using this as an example:

[image: directory]

I get this output:

[image: before]

And I'd like to get this output:

[image: after]

How do I get the find command to return ONLY the file names? No directory names at all.
Is this possible?

As of now I have:

```
"find -x  "+ path + " | sed 's!.*/!!' | grep -v CaptureOne | grep -v .DS_Store | grep -v .cop | grep -v .cof | grep -v .cot | grep -v .cos | grep -v Settings131 | grep -v Proxies | grep -v Thumbnails | grep -v Cache | sort"
```

This *does* get me only the file names and not the full paths. Which I want.
And it doesn't include other file extensions and folders that I **know** will exist.

Like I said - I've never gone down this path and the above code could probably be done in a much easier way. Open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To limit yourself to files, use `-type f` (to exclude directories, you'd use `! -type d`). To get just the basename, pipe the output through `basename`. All together, that'd be:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 basename
```

(The `-print0` and `-0` uses NUL as the separator so that whitespace in pathnames is preserved.)

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks @Rob Napier